# NativeScript + Mapbox pluggin: mapbox.show() error

Tags: mapbox, nativescript

After a lot of try and error, trying to find a solution to [this](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323880/nativescript-addmarkers-outside-of-onmapready/48325114#48325114), I understood thanks to help of Eddy Verbruggen that there two unique way to add markers to mapbox map: by code inside of onMapReady() or programmatically.

But now, I find something that I can not solve: using exactly code indicated [Declaring a map programmatically](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-mapbox/tree/26019957e4e3af3e737d7a44c845f5d5b1bfb808#declaring-a-map-programmatically), when run the app appears errors originated in "TypeError: mapbox.show is not a function".

The code is:

```
`var mapbox = require("nativescript-mapbox");
var platform = require("platform");
var isIOS = platform.device.os === platform.platformNames.ios;

mapbox.show({
accessToken: 'here i wrote my own API ACCESS TOKEN',
style: street, 
margins: {
  left: 40, // default 0
  right: 40, // default 0
  top: 450, // default 0
  bottom: isIOS ? 50: 0 
 },
center: { // optional without a default
  lat: 52.3702160,
  lng: 4.8951680
},
zoomLevel: 9.25, 
showUserLocation: true, 
hideAttribution: false, 
hideLogo: false, 
hideCompass: false, 
disableRotation: false,
disableScroll: false,
disableZoom: false, 
markers: [ 
  {
    id: 1, 
    lat: 52.3732160, 
    lng: 4.8941680, 
    title: 'Nice location', 
    subtitle: 'Really really nice location', 
    icon: 'res://cool_marker', 
    selected: true, 
    onTap: function(marker) { console.log("This marker was tapped"); },
    onCalloutTap: function(marker) { console.log("marker was tapped"); }
  }
 ]
  }).then(
  function(showResult) {
    console.log("Mapbox show done for " + (showResult.ios ? "iOS" : 
 "Android") + ", native object received: " + (showResult.ios ? 
  showResult.ios : showResult.android));
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("mapbox show error: " + error);
  }
)`
```

To clarify, the app is build from "tns create my-app-name --template tns-template-blank". I only added nativescript-mapbox plugin and insert code indicate in "Declaring a map programmatically" inside on home.js file.

I can't understand why appear that error, I'm sure that plugin was correctly installed. The app uses NS version 3.4.1 and nativescript-mapbox version 3.3.0, on Android.